# systemctl failing with unknown section 'Timer'

Tags: rhel, systemd, systemctl

I have a systemctl job that performs vertica backup to s3, i wanted to add a timer that runs everyday at 3am . I tried to create an override file with the timer section but when i do daemon-reload, I am getting an error `Unknown section Timer', I am unable to find the issue.

/etc/systemd/system/vertica-backup.service.d/Override.conf

```
[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 03:00:00
Unit=vertica-backup.service
```

/etc/systemd/system/vertica-backup.service:

```
[Unit]
Description = Vertica Backup Service
After = network.target

[Service]
User= dbadmin
ExecStart= /usr/local/bin/vertica-backup.sh
```

Error

```
May 15 15:19:47 ip-10-150-4-42.ec2.internal systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/vertica-backup.service.d/override.conf:1] Unknown section 'Timer'. Ignoring.
May 15 15:19:50 ip-10-150-4-42.ec2.internal systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/vertica-backup.service.d/override.conf:1] Unknown section 'Timer'. Ignoring.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[Timer]` sections don't go in service files, they go in their own `.timer` files. Create `/etc/systemd/system/vertica-backup.timer` and put the `[Timer]` section in there.

See [`man systemd.timer`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html) for reference.

Answer (score 3):

Create the timer file /etc/systemd/system/vertica-backup.timer

```
[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 03:00:00
Unit=vertica-backup.service
```

verify it

```
sudo systemd-analyze verify /etc/systemd/system/vertica-backup.timer
```

start the timer

```
sudo systemctl start vertica-backup.timer

# check it
systemctl list-timers --all
```

Comment: And do I have to just start and run the timer always that triggers the service OR do I also have to run the service always?